# Netbeans Clamshell emulator out of memory

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, emulation

I have been working with the clamshell mobile phone emulator for netbeans. I recently have tested a simple bluetooth application and got an Out of Memory erorr. Is it possible to up the  amount of memory the emulator can use?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Clamshell mobile phone emulator, though if it is Java program it may be possible that the maximum size of the heap is too small and hence the program is running out of memory.

You can pass `-Xmx512m` as an extra option to Java to set the maximum heap size to `512mb`. (higher values are possible: `-Xmx768m`, `-Xmx1024m`, ...).

So, the only thing left is to find place where your emulator is started. Just add the parameter to the starting script or to the configuration file if there is one.